# Get rid of typical Android bar ( Action bar ) Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hey always when I create an Android App in Xamarin I get the typical Android thing.
How can I remove it?
[image]

I tried

```
 Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
```

and i tried

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

but both didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your activity,if it extends `Activity` ,it will work when you call  `Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);` in the `OnCreate()` method.

If it extends `AppCompatActivity`,it will not work when you set `Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);`,but you could call below codes in your `OnCreate()` method,and it will work.

```
if (SupportActionBar != null)
   {
     SupportActionBar.Hide();
   }
```

Or you could set the theme to `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.